# Wordpress - Commit / Push on gitlab after edit File

Tags: wordpress, git, gitlab

I search for a Solution.
I have many wordpress Projects and now i search for a Plugin:
After edit a File with the WP - Editor, now i commit/push the file on my gitlab project.

thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Hello try this https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-gitlab/ at official sites of Wordpress, I use it for a long time and I feel great

Comment: thanks for help, but Last updated: 3 years ago ! After Install, in the Backend many Error